# saving canvas in php but no data in image file

Tags: php, jquery, html, canvas, base64

Following code i am trying to save canvas on my Machine . in folder image file is created but it is of 0kb .

on click of download button i am setting value in text and on next php page i am reading value with `$_POST['img_name'];` .

JQuery ::

```
$("#Download").click(function() {
    console.log('Download clicked');
    //alert('Download clicked');
    var myval = canvas.toDataURL();
    $('#img_txt').val(myval);
});
```

php code ::

```
<?php
$myval = $_POST['img_name'];
echo "string is ".$myval; 
?>

<?php
$data = base64_decode($_POST['img_name']);

/* Name the file anything you want */
$filename = 'my_image.png';

/* Remove 1st line of base64 string */ 
/* Note: replace '$base64' with your own variable */
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);


/* Replace spaces */
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

/* Decode string */
$data = base64_decode($img);

/* Full path to upload directory with at the end the filename */
$file = 'D:/upload/'.$filename;

/* Save, make sure the directory is writeable! */
file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

I have check $_POST['img_name'] i am getting base64 string ? what is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jQuery isn't sending anything to your .php

Try this:

```
// convert the canvas to base64 data

var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL();

// call upload.php and post the data

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "upload.php",
  data: {image: dataURL}
}).done(function( respond ) {
 console.log("Saved filename: "+respond);
});
```

Your upload file should remove the datatype prefix before decoding.

Try this for upload.php:

```
<?php 
if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) { 

    // get the image data
    $data = $_POST['image'];

    // remove the prefix
    $uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",") 1);

    // create a filename for the new image
    $file = md5(uniqid()) . '.png';

    // decode the image data and save it to file
    file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($uri));

    // return the filename
    echo $file;

}
```

Also, make sure your php server is configured:

- Assign an upload directory
- Give write permission to the upload directory

Answer (score 5):

Replace upload.php file

if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) {

```
// get the image data
$data = $_POST['image'];

// remove the prefix
$uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);

// create a filename for the new image
$file = md5(uniqid()) . '.png';

// decode the image data and save it to file
file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($uri));

// return the filename
echo $file;
```

}

Comment: Better answer than the accepted one because of <code>$uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);</code>

Answer (score 1):

I used Following code to save base64 as an image,

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"])) {

    // get the image data
    $data = $_POST['image'];

    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    //Image name
    //  $filename ="image". md5(uniqid()) . '.png';
    $filename = "Post_Card.png";

    $file = '../ReportCard/' . $filename;

    // decode the image data and save it to file
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
    echo $file;
}
?>
```

If require we can use following code to give random generated names to file ,

```
// create a filename for the new image
$file = md5(uniqid()) . '.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a png format?

because when you run the method `toDataURL();` the default is PNG you cant try `toDataURL("image/jpeg");` or any other format that correspond wit your need.

And you might want to consider uploading it to PHP so you can save it on your server in a directory let's say `Pics`.